# Shortest path to an exit going through a key (Dijkstra)

Tags: python, graph, path, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

In a directed and weighted graph, there are at most V exits scattered among the vertices, denoted by exits = [v1,v2, ...]. In order to exit the graph through an exit, you will have to pass through a key which the key itself is weighted. You can choose whether to take the key or pass through it to find another key that has less weight. There are also at most V keys scattered among the vertices, denoted by keys = [(k1, weight), ...]. You should return a tuple (shortest distance (total weight), the path from the source to the exit).

Using Dijkstra's algorithm, I have managed to find the shortest paths to each vertex from the source. A solution I can think of is to then run the dijkstra algorithm from all of the keys I have found to find the shortest exit from the key. I would then compare the sum of the distance of the closest exit from the key and the distance of closest key from the source from each dijkstra and find the shortest one. However this would result in V * ElogV time complexity. Is there anyway I could implement this to be at most ElogV?

Comment: Before you go chasing after novel algorithms you should implement the one you have.  Does it give the correct answer?  Does it run fast enough for your performance requirement? ( You do have a performance requirement, I expect )  If the answer to both questions is yes, then you are done and can move on to something else.  If not, then post what you tried and we can try and help.